# Is 'List.empty(growable: false)' or 'const []' more efficient in Dart?

Tags: list, flutter, performance, dart

Hello fellow Coders,
I was wondering whether `const []` is more efficient than `List.empty(growable: false)`. The latter sound more like the official way to go about it, but because I can't make it const it has to allocates a new array. Whereas the first is not only shorter but because it is const I don't see how it isn't more efficient.
Does anyone has more insight/ knows how to check the actual performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const <T>[]` creates a canonical, compile-time constant.  The `List<T>` object is constructed only once.

In contrast, `List<T>.empty(growable: false)` has no such guarantee and can create new `List<T>` objects. (Arguably it could return a `const List<T>` object when `growable` is `false`, but then that would require a runtime check on `growable`, so that too would be slightly less efficient.  As you've already noted, it can't do any *better* than `const <T>[]`.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the second, with List.empty actually clears the current list, without creating a reference to a new one, regardless if `= []` or `= const []`. Interesting question though.

Comment: Wait, just so that we're on the same page: I'm not talking about `instanceOfList.empty()`, im talking about the static method from the List class - literally `List.empty`. One of the few legal constructors of list.